# How to use a sprinkler valve in multiple zones?

Tags: diodes, ac, circuit-design, rectifier, solenoid-valve

I am currently setting up an outside irrigation system.  When I built the system, I thought the irrigation controller would allow me to power multiple zones at the same time, and that each valve -  could be plugged in and used as a zone.  Unfortunately, that’s not how it works — only one zone is powered at a time, and multiple valves can be wired to a single zone.

My problem is: when you wire a valve to be in two zones, the current back feeds and turns on incorrect valves in another zone.

I did some research ([How to keep voltage when using two diodes to run two irrigation stations?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104399/how-to-keep-voltage-when-using-two-diodes-to-run-two-irrigation-stations)) and found that if I use a full rectifier and diode on the hot wire to each valve, I can accomplish what I want.  I diagrammed out the idea that I think will work, but I’m concerned about how the circuit will work when going through the rectifier from the common line — it looks like it will still power valves that I don’t want to power.

My question is: how can I prevent the common wire from sending current to the undesired valves from the rectifier?  (Not pictured in diagram)

Other notes: The controller uses a common wire (shared to all valves), and a hot wire (24VAC@1a) individually to each zone.

[image: Circuit diagram of sprinkler setup]

Comment: What I mean by this is:  manifold 2 is in zone 2,3,4.  Valve 1 is in zone 2.  Valve 2 and 3 are in zone 3.  

Without the use of diodes, I don’t know how to prevent sending power to valve 2/3 when powering zone 2 because they share a connection to manifold 2.

Comment: you linked a similar question ... why did you not follow the connection diagram in that question? ... it appears to be the solution to your problem

Comment: The specific confusion I have relates to the handling of the negative polarity (common) on the AC cycle.  This was not discussed in the linked question.  If I were to connect ‘common’ to the rectifiers in my diagram, it seems like they would send power to valves that I don’t want to send power to.

Comment: it looks like your circuit should work as intended ... you do not need the bridge rectifiers at all

Comment: Is there danger in damaging the solenoid by only using the positive cycle (and ignoring the negative cycle) from the AC current?

Comment: it is possible that the solenoid plunger could become magnetized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get there from here... diodes can't steer the AC suffciiently on both halves of the AC cycle.

If you put diodes in for the other half-cycle there's a back path that powers the zones that should be off.

consider zones 5 and 6

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV8CPH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm sure you've figured out that this will not work:
when zone 5 is on current can flow through D1 and D4 during the positive half and through D2 and D3 during the negative half. in each case reaching zone6 which is not wanted.

If the manifold solenoid will work from DC you can do this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYyKfa.png)</sup>

If it does not you will need to use a relay designed for AC operation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ojxL.png)</sup>

Or maybe use triacs to gate the power to the manifold solenoid.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJRNHo.png)</sup>